# How can I get the LVC exchange in RabbitMQ to persist the cached value across RabbitMQ executions?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am exploring the use of an LVC exchange for the use of stateful notifications.  When the state changes, subscribers need to be told about it.  The LVC exchange is valuable for this when services are not necessarily always up and not guaranteed to be started in any order.

A persistent and durable queue would mostly allow me the same function, but if down for an extended period, the queue size might grow large without need and the queue reader might have to deal with a lot of unnecessary messages.

I am running RabbitMQ in a docker container.  I have verified that the exchange itself is in fact durable and the mnesia datastore is mapped outside the container.

1. Start RabbitMQ
2. Publish message to exchange (producer.rb)
3. Listen for messages using an anonymous queue bound to the exchange
4. See that the Last Value is received
5. Stop RabbitMQ
6. Start RabbitMQ
7. Listen for messages using an anonymous queue bound to the exchange

producer.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bunny'
connection = Bunny.new
connection.start
channel = connection.create_channel

message = "Hello World! #{Time.new}"
exchange = channel.exchange('pub-sub', :durable => true, :type => 'x-lvc')
exchange.publish(message, :persistent => true)
puts " [x] Sent '#{message}'"
```

consumer.rb

```
require 'bunny'
connection = Bunny.new()
connection.start
channel = connection.create_channel
queue = channel.queue('', exclusive: true)
queue.bind('pub-sub')

begin
  puts ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
  queue.subscribe(block: true) do |_delivery_info, _properties, body|
    puts " [x] Received #{body}"
  end
rescue Interrupt => _
  connection.close
end
```

I expected to see the same message that was originally published, instead I got no new messages.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

This feature request was reported as [GitHub issue #21](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-lvc-exchange/issues/21) and has been implemented. Now the `disc_copies` option is passed to `create_table` and persistence of the last value is implemented.

Original answer:

I reviewed the source code for that plugin and I suspect what you're seeing is due to how the backend for this plugin is setup: [code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-lvc-exchange/blob/master/src/rabbit_lvc_plugin.erl). Notice that no `disc_copies` option is passed to [`create_table`](https://erldocs.com/current/mnesia/mnesia.html?i=0&search=create_table#create_table/2), thus the data resides only in RAM.

If you'd take the time to open an issue in that repository I may be able to fix this issue relatively easily.